# Cannot connect to Azure or Graph with an automation account

Tags: powershell, automation, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to automate the setting of advanced auditing attributes on AAD accounts using Nathan McNulty's excellent blog here: [Azure Automation - Advanced Auditing](https://blog.nathanmcnulty.com/azure-automation-advanced-auditing/)

In it one uses a PS script in a runbook to set these attributes on the members of dynamic group. He supplies the script to use, and the very first few lines where it connects to AZ and mgraph are where I'm running into trouble:

```
**# Connect to Microsoft Graph within Azure Automation
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$token = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com"
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $token.Token**
```

When I attempt to test this section of code, it immediately spews out a red tsunami of errors, which more or less boil down to:

> "System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException: Cannot bind parameter 'AccessToken'. Cannot convert the "very long char string" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".. ---> System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidCastException: Cannot convert the "same very long char string" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".
> at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ThrowInvalidCastException(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType) blah, blah, blah..."

It seems that the good Mr. McNulty is not presently reachable however. I've been Googling this section of code and it seems to be a rather unusual way of connecting for some reason. Troubleshooting this, however, is way beyond me. Anyone got any ideas as to what's going wrong, or a workaround? Pretend you're talking to a 10 year old... Thanks tons for your collective expertise!

Comment: `-AccessToken` was changed in latest version of this module, now it takes a secure string as input so you would need to `Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken ($token.Token | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)`

Comment: "Welcome To Microsoft Graph!" Thanks so much; you rule!

Answer (score 0):

The error ***"Cannot bind parameter 'AccessToken'"*** usually occurs if the access token is not passed correctly in the command while connecting to MgGraph.

I agree with ***@Santiago Squarzon***, to resolve the error modify the script like below:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$token = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com"
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken ($token.Token | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
```

[image]

Now to enable the advanced auditing for the Group members use the below script by *@Nathan McNulty* in this [**blog**](https://blog.nathanmcnulty.com/azure-automation-advanced-auditing/).

```
$groupId = (Get-MgGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq 'xxx'").Id
$groupMembers = (Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $groupId -All | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AdditionalProperties).mail
Connect-ExchangeOnline -ManagedIdentity -Organization $tenantName -Verbose

Get-Mailbox -Identity $groupMembers[0] | Out-Null

$groupMembers | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output $_
    Set-Mailbox -Identity $_ -AuditAdmin @{add="Create","FolderBind","SendAs"} -AuditDelegate @{add="Create","FolderBind","SendAs"}
}
```

For **sample** I set the Mailbox auditing only for one user:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com

Set-Mailbox -Identity user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com -AuditAdmin @{add="Create","FolderBind","SendAs"}
```

[image]